# How to retrieve observation scores for each Principal Component in R using principal Function

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

```
pc_unrotate = principal(correlate1,nfactors = 4,rotate = "none")
print(pc_unrotate)

output: 
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = correlate1, nfactors = 4, rotate = "none")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
              PC1   PC2   PC3   PC4   h2    u2 com
ProdQual     0.25 -0.50 -0.08  0.67 0.77 0.232 2.2
Ecom         0.31  0.71  0.31  0.28 0.78 0.223 2.1
TechSup      0.29 -0.37  0.79 -0.20 0.89 0.107 1.9
CompRes      0.87  0.03 -0.27 -0.22 0.88 0.119 1.3
Advertising  0.34  0.58  0.11  0.33 0.58 0.424 2.4
ProdLine     0.72 -0.45 -0.15  0.21 0.79 0.213 2.0
SalesFImage  0.38  0.75  0.31  0.23 0.86 0.141 2.1
ComPricing  -0.28  0.66 -0.07 -0.35 0.64 0.359 1.9
WartyClaim   0.39 -0.31  0.78 -0.19 0.89 0.108 2.0
OrdBilling   0.81  0.04 -0.22 -0.25 0.77 0.234 1.3
DelSpeed     0.88  0.12 -0.30 -0.21 0.91 0.086 1.4

                       PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4
SS loadings           3.43 2.55 1.69 1.09
Proportion Var        0.31 0.23 0.15 0.10
Cumulative Var        0.31 0.54 0.70 0.80
Proportion Explained  0.39 0.29 0.19 0.12
Cumulative Proportion 0.39 0.68 0.88 1.00
```

Mean item complexity =  1.9
Test of the hypothesis that 4 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.06

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.97

Now i need to get the scores, Tried pc_unrotate$scores but it returns null.

executed names(pc_unrotate),
[Name of PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVmks.png)
and found that Scores attribute is missing...so what can i do to get PCA scores?

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. Removed 'mlr' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add argument `scores=TRUE` to the `principal()` function call: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.9.12.31/topics/principal

```r
pc_unrotate = principal(correlate1,nfactors = 4,rotate = "none", scores = TRUE)
```

Comment: Tried adding but still it is not available.
pc_unrotate = principal(correlate1,nfactors = 4,rotate = "none",scores =TRUE)
names(pc_unrotate)
pc_unrotate$scores

Comment: Please try giving a full working example - please show contents (fake if You wish) of `correlate1` object - `dput` function could help - add output of `dput(correlate1)`

Comment: dput(correlate1)
 1), .Dim = c(11L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("ProdQual", "Ecom", "TechSup", "CompRes", "Advertising", 
    "ProdLine", "SalesFImage", "ComPricing", "WartyClaim", "OrdBilling", 
    "DelSpeed"), c("ProdQual", "Ecom", "TechSup", "CompRes", 
    "Advertising", "ProdLine", "SalesFImage", "ComPricing", "WartyClaim", 
    "OrdBilling", "DelSpeed")))

Comment: The output seems incomplete - it shows only names of the dimensions but not the values (rows).

Comment: I suggest you to check this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/interpreting-pca-scores and this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222/what-are-principal-component-scores. I think that you should find all you need.